# Is there a way to get Doxygen to recognize Exception class when prefix with backslash?

Tags: php, global, doxygen

It seems when I use the @throws in my comment block and key out \Exception (notice the backslash to indicate global namespace) for the exception object that is thrown, Doxygen isn't parsing this properly. Below are screenshots of my comment and the end result. Notice how it just says "Exceptions", but doesn't list out all the exception objects that are thrown and the corresponding comment. Removing the backslash resolves this but I'm hesitant to do this because it makes my code inconsistent. I use backslash wherever I reference global classes because I'm working within my own namespace.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the `@throws` notation appears to be [`phpDoc` format](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/throws.html), not Doxygen. In phpDoc, the [class _must_ be fully-qualifed](https://docs.phpdoc.org/glossary.html#term-type). Are you using a render tool that understands phpDoc syntax?

Comment: Hi bishop, I'm not sure I understand your last question. Would you be able to clarify? The first part of your answer seems to address the issue though. It sounds like Doxygen doesn't recognize fully qualified namespaces. In the Doxygen output, I do see other warnings about it not recognize things like \DOMDocument, so it sounds like using this in my comments isn't going to work perfectly with Doxygen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, it looks like the preferred solution is to pass an INPUT_FILTER through Doxygen to remove these backslashes.